# Error in creation intersection of two series with Python

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to create a program to intersect two series. Everything is OK, but Python gives me an empty list as a result. The code is:

```
 def intersect(s1,s2):
    res=[]
    for x in s1:
        if x in s2:
            res.append(x)
        return res
```

I write :

```
>>> intersect([1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7])
```

And then the program gives me that:

[]

Comment: You can simply change your code to `return list(set(s1).intersection(set(s2)))`

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `return res` back one level, because at the moment you're returning on the first run through the loop, and thus getting an empty list.

i.e. you should have:

```
def intersect(s1,s2):
    res=[]
    for x in s1:
        if x in s2:
            res.append(x)
    return res # note this is unindented
```

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect for your `return` line.

However, you should use `set.intersection` (denoted also by `&`) to calculate intersection:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [3,4,5,6,7]

res = sorted(set(a) & set(b))

print(res)

# [3, 4, 5]
```